# LOAD DATA INFILE to load data into different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Company(id int, varchar(name), primary key(id));
Product (id int, c_id int, varchar(name), foreign key(c_id), references Company(id));
```

Table 'Company' stores a list of company names and 'Product' stores a list of product names, and one company can have multiple products.

If I have data file like this, tab delimited:

```
1  Apple  iPhone
2  Apple  iPad
3  Apple  iMac
4  Google Gmail
5  Google Google Search
6  Amazon Kindle
```

Is it possible to use "Load DATA INFILE" to load this file into two tables, where the first column goes to table Company and second coloumn goes to Product? The question is how to load selected fields to a particular table, instead of loading the full record into one table.

Comment: Are these new tables or do they already exist?  What about the `id` fields in these tables?  You don't have data for both id's.

Comment: Two tables already existed. I can remove the id from the file, if it makes the loading easier, but each table has a 'id' as the primary key.

Comment: `LOAD DATA` does have the possibility to selectively load only certain columns, but the order appears to be dictated by the CSV file.  So I am not sure that there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: Then how can I load this file into two tables? This should be a very common scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can try an approach like this, with the premise of using a temporary table. I hope you find it useful.

/path/to/file/file.csv

```bsh
1,Apple,iPhone
2,Apple,iPad
3,Apple,iMac
4,Google,Gmail
5,Google,Google Search
6,Amazon,Kindle
```

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `from_load_data`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_company_product`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `company` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     `name` VARCHAR(25),
    ->     UNIQUE KEY `unique_name` (`name`)
    -> )//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `product` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     `c_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->     `name` VARCHAR(25),
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `company`(`id`)
    ->         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> )//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `temp_company_product` (
    ->     `id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    ->     `company_name` VARCHAR(25),
    ->     `product_name` VARCHAR(25)
    -> )//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `from_load_data` AFTER INSERT ON `temp_company_product`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     INSERT INTO `company` (`name`) VALUES (NEW.`company_name`)
    ->         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`);
    ->     INSERT INTO `product` (`c_id`, `name`)
    ->     SELECT `id`, NEW.`product_name`
    ->     FROM `company`
    ->     WHERE `name` = NEW.`company_name`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/file.csv'
    ->     INTO TABLE `temp_company_product`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    -> (`id`, `company_name`, `product_name`)//
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->     `id`,
    ->     `company_name`,
    ->     `product_name`
    -> FROM
    ->     `temp_company_product`//
+----+--------------+---------------+
| id | company_name | product_name  |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 | Apple        | iPhone        |
|  2 | Apple        | iPad          |
|  3 | Apple        | iMac          |
|  4 | Google       | Gmail         |
|  5 | Google       | Google Search |
|  6 | Amazon       | Kindle        |
+----+--------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     `id`,
    ->     `name`
    -> FROM
    ->     `company`//
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  6 | Amazon |
|  1 | Apple  |
|  4 | Google |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     `id`,
    ->     `c_id`,
    ->     `name`
    -> FROM
    ->     `product`//
+----+------+---------------+
| id | c_id | name          |
+----+------+---------------+
|  1 |    1 | iPhone        |
|  2 |    1 | iPad          |
|  3 |    1 | iMac          |
|  4 |    4 | Gmail         |
|  5 |    4 | Google Search |
|  6 |    6 | Kindle        |
+----+------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `from_load_data`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_company_product`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that `LOAD DATA` is flexible enough to allow to you selectively load certain columns into two different already-existing tables.  It was designed to be a fast work horse, but was not designed to be particularly flexible.  An alternative would be to load your data into a temporary table, and then `INSERT INTO...SELECT` the data into your two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE temp(id int, company varchar(55), product varchar(55));

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, company, product);
```

And then just use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` to get the data into your two tables which already exist:

```
INSERT INTO Company (name)
SELECT company
FROM temp

INSERT INTO Product (name)
SELECT product
FROM temp
```

Comment: This issue is that, in Product, it also needs to insert a field 'c_id', in addition to 'name', which creates the relationship between Company and Product. Please see the table definitions.

Comment: From where is `c_id` coming in your input csv file?  This was not clear to me.

Comment: c_id isn't in the csv file. So probably it's better to split the csv file into two, to make the life easier.

Comment: I think splitting the CSV file into two makes life harder.  I also don't see why you can't adapt my answer to give you the result you want.  Try it out and see how far you get.

Comment: But it is not possible to have the c_id field in one file. That information is implicit in the file. For example, the Product table should have iPhone,iPad and iMac all have a field of c_id = "1", which points to the Apple in the Company table.

Comment: Please sort out your source data issues and then come back here.

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful.

Comment: If my "file.csv" is under c:/file.csv, how to specify the file path in "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE temp"?

Comment: With a trigger in the temporary table you can accomplish what you need. Note that you will lose some performance.

Comment: how to specify the file path to "file.csv"?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?  Where is the file located?

Comment: Linux, See LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/abigail/Company.txt' INTO TABLE Company FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  ENCLOSED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (id,name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)                 
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: I suggested loading the file into a _new_ temporary table, but you are trying to load into the `Company` table instead.  I don't think this will work because the columns don't match up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I split the file into two, because that's the only way I can get it to work. Now, why it doesn't load. Company table have only two fields, "id" and "name". Is that because I am using a tab '\t', instead of comma as delimiter? also, I am using a .txt not .csv extension.